# Trap choices for Hunter

Tags: hearthstone

There seems to be a strong consensus about which traps to use when playing Hunter right now: Face Hunter uses explosive trap, midrange Hunter uses freeze trap. Of course some players deviate from this, but if you look at the decklists of professional or high-ranked players the trap choices seem to be very consistent.

What are the reasons for these choices? I can think of a few reasons for them, but I could also see how explosive trap would be good in midrage hunter or to a lesser extent freeze trap in Face Hunter.

And what about Snake trap? I've seen it played even at high levels a few times, but aside from the surprise factor I can't really see the appeal.

Answer (score 7):

Explosive trap does 2 damage to all enemies.  That includes the enemy player, which is why it is in the Face Hunter.

Frost trap returns an attacking enemy minion back to their hand.  If the trap returns a 5 mana or more minion, that's a large tempo swing (5 or more mana) for the cost of 1 card.

Snake Trap is mostly about combos.  Knife Juggler, Starving Buzzard, Scavenging Hyena, Timber Wolf.

Misdirection and Snipe are about plan disruption, rather than outright card, tempo, or combo advantages.

Comment: Keep in mind that snake trap + knife juggler can actually save your attacked minion from taking any damage from an attack. As the snakes are summoned, the daggers can kill the attacking minion before it deals its attack damage to its target.

Comment: This answer is correct, but it could use some additional explanation. Why is Explosive Trap _not_ in Midrange Hunter? Why is Freezing Trap _not_ in Face Hunter? Why is a large tempo swing something that Midrange Hunter cares about but not Face Hunter?

Comment: @ken.ganong Those questions are easily answered by the definitions of those decks - definitions which are prerequisites for having those questions.  I choose to answer the question asked, and not write an article or post decklists (unhelpful actions in this context).

Comment: @ken.ganong Consider that a freezing trap triggers on *an enemy minion attacking*, while explosive traps triggers on *your hero being attacked*. If you have a solid board of minions, odds are your explosive trap is useless since the enemy focuses on killing your minions. Freezing trap is great if the enemy only has one or two *large* minions (not enemies to AOE with explosive).